# Como llamar un Servicio web a mi aplicacion Silverlight 4 en C#

Tags: c#, webservice, silverlight

Tengo la siguiente duda, como puedo mandar llamar un servicio web a mi aplicación de silverlight, para consumir mi servicio web a mi proyecto silverlight 4, no tengo mucha experiencia en consumos de servicios web

Si me pudieran explicar como hacerlo, gracias

Comment: que tipo de servicio web? es un asmx o sea de asp.net, es un .svc o sea de WCF, es una web api de asp.net mvc, quizas un servicio con otra tecnologia

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  Estoy tratando de conectarlo de dos maneras de servicio web de tipo asmx y de .svc, para tener el conocimiento de hacerlo con los dos tipos, o para ambos tipos es igual el llamado